# How can I make Google+ give me desktop notifications?

Tags: google-plus, notifications

How can I make Google+ show notifications in the Mac OS X menu bar?

[image: i can has this?]

I believe that menu bar icon is showing me *Desktop Notifications*. I have those enabled... and I have no exceptions set for Google's domains, and can't add one:

[image]

Desktop Notifications are also not working for http://chat.stackexchange.com/ `:'(`

Do these sites just not provide Desktop Notifications? I know Stack Exchange used to! I can't imagine Google's own software doesn't..?

Comment: It seems Google+ does not provide desktop notifications